# Partial Fraction Expansion of numerous terms multiplied and added, containing a complex variable

Tags: complex-analysis, summation, partial-fractions

[Here is the link for the picture containing the equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQFfg.png)

The picture contains a general example of partial fraction expansion for transfer functions (electronic engineering stuff). They substitute in s = jw, but I don't understand how they got rid of so many terms doing this. I have done my own example (the second link provided) but I don't understand how they have effectively gotten rid of the majority of the RHS.

[My example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1qw4.jpg)

ie. I do not understand how line 3 goes to line 4 in the second link provided.
I know I am missing an omega (w) on the LHS (line 1 to line 2) but this doesn't change anything

A clear explanation is appreciated, I am not used to the notation.

Comment: Mathematical expressions can be posted here directly [using MathJax](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and $\LaTeX$ markup.  The substitution $s = j\omega$ causes $s^2 = -\omega^2$, and thus the factor $(s^2 + \omega^2)$ vanishes, simplifying a great deal.  We need to work on getting your Question into a more readable form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that $j^2 = -1$

So in that summation you end up with $-w^2 + w^2$